# OLS Breusch Pagan test in Python

Tags: python, statistics, canopy, pysal

I used the `statsmodels` package to estimate my OLS regression. Now I want `Breusch Pagan test`. I used the `pysal` package for this test but this function returns an error:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pysal

model = sm.OLS(Y,X,missing = 'drop')
rs = model.fit()
pysal.spreg.diagnostics.breusch_pagan(rs)
```

returned error:

> AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'u'

What should I do?

Comment: I don't know about the exception, but you could also use breushpagan from statsmodels, which takes OLS residuals and candidates for explanatory variables for the heteroscedasticity, http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breushpagan.html  with examples here http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/regression_diagnostics.html

Comment: Thank you. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the regression results instance of statsmodels is not compatible with the one in pysal.

You can use `breuschpagan` from statsmodels, which takes OLS residuals and candidates for explanatory variables for the heteroscedasticity and so it does not rely on a specific model or implementation of a model.

documentation:
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan.html

with examples here https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/regression_diagnostics.html

I do not know if there are any essential differences in the implementation of the Breusch-Pagan test.

It looks like the name is misspelled in statsmodels.

**edit** The spelling of the name has been corrected in statsmodels version 0.9.
The old incorrect spelling was `breushpagan`.

Comment: Seems the old links have broken. This blog: https://www.statology.org/breusch-pagan-test-python/ tells about the test, how to implement it using statsmodel in a verbose and explicit manner.

Comment: I fixed the links and adjusted to the corrected spelling of `breuschpagan` which was missing a "c"

Answer (score 2):

As I tend not to use the statsmodels library, I have created a Python function to perform the Breusch-Pagan test. It uses multiple linear regression from SciKit-learn.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from scipy.stats import chisqprob


def breusch_pagan_test(x, y):
    '''
    Breusch-Pagan test for heteroskedasticity in a linear regression model:
    H_0 = No heteroskedasticity.
    H_1 = Heteroskedasticity is present.

    Inputs:
    x = a numpy.ndarray containing the predictor variables. Shape = (nSamples, nPredictors).
    y = a 1D numpy.ndarray containing the response variable. Shape = (nSamples, ).

    Outputs a list containing three elements:
    1. the Breusch-Pagan test statistic.
    2. the p-value for the test.
    3. the test result.
    '''

    if y.ndim != 1:
        raise SystemExit('Error: y has more than 1 dimension.')
    if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
        raise SystemExit('Error: the number of samples differs between x and y.')
    else:
        n_samples = y.shape[0]

    # fit an OLS linear model to y using x:
    lm = LinearRegression()
    lm.fit(x, y)

    # calculate the squared errors:
    err = (y - lm.predict(x))**2

    # fit an auxiliary regression to the squared errors:
    # why?: to estimate the variance in err explained by x
    lm.fit(x, err)
    pred_err = lm.predict(x)
    del lm

    # calculate the coefficient of determination:
    ss_tot = sum((err - np.mean(err))**2)
    ss_res = sum((err - pred_err)**2)
    r2 = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)
    del err, pred_err, ss_res, ss_tot

    # calculate the Lagrange multiplier:
    LM = n_samples * r2
    del r2

    # calculate p-value. degrees of freedom = number of predictors.
    # this is equivalent to (p - 1) parameter restrictions in Wikipedia entry.
    pval = chisqprob(LM, x.shape[1])

    if pval < 0.01:
        test_result = 'Heteroskedasticity present at 99% CI.'
    elif pval < 0.05:
        test_result = 'Heteroskedasticity present at 95% CI.'
    else:
        test_result = 'No significant heteroskedasticity.'
    return [LM, pval, test_result]
```

Comment: Just to note, the `chisqprob` is deprecated, and `scipy.stats.distributions.chi2.sf` is the suggested alternative : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisqprob.html

Comment: If x is list of graphs represented by id, nbr_of_edges, nbr_of_nodes & y is a computed index on the graph, like connectivity index, ... is that valid input?

Comment: Hi sAguinaga, I'm sorry for the late reply. Its been a while since I wrote this, but "x" is just a numpy array containing the predictor variables in a linear regression. For example, if you have 100 training samples (i.e. unique data points) and each has 5 predictor variables, x.shape=(100, 5).

Comment: Small correction: the Breusch-Pagan test regresses the normalized errors onto the predictors. So `resid**2 / mean(resid**2)` instead of just `resid**2`. This is what they refer to as `g` in the original paper.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I was unaware of this.